# Thousands of views on a question. Due to many users looking a few times or a few users looking many times?

Tags: discussion

The following question currently has 19K views.

[What (modern) weapons could be used to destroy skeletal enemies as completely as possible?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/136083/what-modern-weapons-could-be-used-to-destroy-skeletal-enemies-as-completely-as)

I'm not so naive as to suppose that 19K different people have looked at it. Clearly some people have looked many times at the same question. What is the distribution though?

**Question**

Are there - or could there be - statistics for

(a) how many *different* users have viewed any particular question (as opposed to the raw number of views)

(b) the frequency distribution (anonymous) of multiple views per individual

(c) also relevant -  how many users have been active on the site as a whole in a particular period, e.g. January 2019. Given the above stats, this can be used to work out what proportion of active users have looked at a particular question.

---

**Notes**

I'm curious as to how many users are currently active on Worldbuilding (as opposed to the total of those who have registered since it began).

By a user being active, I literally mean any activity including asking a question, answering, commenting, moderating or in particular simply reading a question.

Maybe this could be determined simply by counting users who logged on during that time.

Comment: Take a freshly posted question: note the number of views, view the question, go back to the question list. Do it once again. The view counter doesn't increase.

Comment: @L.Dutch - So repeat views by an individual aren't recorded? Does that mean they are unrecoverable?  If so, I have to move on to question (c) to find out what proportion of the active-user base has viewed a given question at least once.

Comment: I think the view counter tracks unique views. But I leave that answer to someone more acknowledgeable.

Comment: @L.Dutch If I remember correctly, it doesn't track unique views, but if you visit a page multiple times within [15?] minutes, it will only count the visits as one view. I think that if the visits are separated by >= 15 minutes, they'll be counted as multiple visits. At the same time, chasly, 19,000 views isn't surprisingly large. Hundreds of thousands of people use the network every *day*; some questions just get lucky enough to get seen by many of them.

Comment: FWIW, this question was featured on the hot network sidebar.

Comment: Actually I'm wondering if I should have put this on the main site Meta.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I'd hazard a guess there is an answer to this question on meta.se

Comment: Re: (c), if "reputation" indicates "activeness", then [the monthly league reputation](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/579/month/worldbuilding) tracks the "reputation change"

Comment: naive? You were a featured user a few days ago on the main SE page feed. I never got around to making the joke about how it seems you're single handedly keeping SE alive atm. 'people reached' in your profile is bs IMO, but 20k people *did* read that question ;)

Comment: You ask a question basically every day that goes straight to the HNQ. I hereby grant you the honorary badge of Title Master.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this hasn't changed in the past ~7-8 years, then views are counted as per [HDE's comment](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7082/thousands-of-views-on-a-question-due-to-many-users-looking-a-few-times-or-a-few?cb=1#comment22349_7082) and explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/349720):

> There is some sort of a throttling mechanism in action. It saves the information about a question view per visitor like in pairs:
>
> - for anonymous users, it is IP + QuestionNr.
> - for authenticated users it is UserNr + QuestionNr.
>
> This information is saved in an expiring cache entry for about 15 minutes. If a subsequent hit sees the entry is still there it discards the new hit. If it is already gone it allows for a new record.

That is, any time a post receives a view from a user (or IP address) that it hasn't seen within about 15 minutes, checked against a cache, it adds the user number (or IP address) to this cache.

When a new cache entry is created, a buffer is also updated:

> The buffer itself also expires after a few minutes or after it is filled up to a certain size, whichever happens first. When it expires, everything it has accumulated is written into the database in bulk. They call it a "buffered write scheme".

So, in essence, each unique view within an approximately 15 minute window adds an entry to a buffer which updates the number of displayed page views by the number in that buffer either after a few minutes, or once it's full (whichever is first).

---

All in all, this gives that, as the data is only *temporarily* stored, there's just no way of being able to answer parts (a) or (b) of your question - a quick check on the stored database values in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) confirms this.

A partial answer to part (c) can at least be found by doing a SEDE search by 'LastAccessDate', which could be used to return the users who *last* accessed the site within a certain time period/since a certain date. For completeness, I [ran this](https://data.stackexchange.com/worldbuilding/query/edit/974882#messages) and got 9562 results.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there are three major reasons for such view counts.

1. A question is on a topic that people generally search for on search engines.
2. A question is linked to on a popular blog, Twitter account, Facebook, etc.
3. A question hits the Stack Exchange "Hot Network Questions", which causes it to be featured in the sidebar network wide, and thus viewed by a massively larger audience than only those who browse Worldbuilding regularly.

On #1 and #2, the vote count is typically not that high, as most of the visitiors are not SE users, and thus do not have enough reputation to vote.

On #3, a fair portion of the visitors are SE users with reputation from other sites, who thus can get the association bonus, and vote. Therefore, #3 results in considerably higher vote count than #1 and #2.

Due to the reasonably high vote count on your question (and its answers), #3 seems more likely.

We can [use the Wayback Machine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279509/321647) to confirm that your question was indeed a "Hot Network Question", in fact, it was at the top of the list, with over 200k hotness points shortly after it was asked.

[image]

So actually, it is quite possible that the number of unique visitors is quite high, perhaps higher than you expect.